# java.lang.StackOverflowError on a recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, random, logic, java-11

I want to draw a random card from a deck and validates that it's always unique. I'm using the cardGenerator() recursive function to do that. If the random card picked has been shown then it calls itself again. Need a work around or if any of yall got a better logic please let me know.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class App {
    static ArrayList<Integer[]> deck = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer[]> dealer = new ArrayList<>();

    static Integer[] cardGenerator() throws Exception{
        Random random = new Random();
        Integer[] card = {0, 0};
        Integer num = random.nextInt(13);
        Integer shape = random.nextInt(4);
        Integer[] deckSet = deck.get(num);
        if(deckSet[shape] == 1){
            deckSet[shape] = 0;
            deck.set(num, deckSet);
            card[0] = num;
            card[1] = shape;
            return card;
        }
        else return cardGenerator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Integer[] deckSet = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
            deck.add(deckSet);
        }
        dealer.add(cardGenerator());
        dealer.add(cardGenerator());
        dealer.add(cardGenerator());
        dealer.add(cardGenerator());
        dealer.add(cardGenerator());
    }
}
```

expecting for dealer to store 5 unique cards, but java.lang.StackOverflowError occured on the cardGenerator function.

Comment: I have not worked with Java in a while, but did you just assign the same reference to the array to all of the ArrayList? Try drawing 4 cards, and let me know if it works. I think you need to make a new array of { 1 1 1 1 } for each of the numbers from 1 - 13, or else the ArrayList just repeatedly point to the same array.

Comment: yes i did do that and i've edited the question

Comment: Ok, my suspicions are correct: you need to make a new array for each element of the ArrayList, or else every element in the ArrayList is pointing to the same array. So for each of the 4 draws, it will turn 1 number in { 1, 1, 1, 1 } into 0, and on the 5th draw, a stack overflow occurs as there is no more 1s in the shared array.

Comment: Don’t use `Integer` where an `int` will do. You can replace all occurrences of `Integer` in your code with `int` which will improve robustness (an `int` can never be `null`) and performance (no conversions between `int` and `Integer`).

Answer (score 1):

You use the same `deckSet` array for all deck numbers. That means that after drawing for cards for all deck numbers the deckSet will be `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

To solve it you need to initialize the `deck` as

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        Integer[] deckSet = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        deck.add(deckSet);
    }
```

Comment: @Lawrance in your questions code you create only one `deckSet` before the loop. You **must** move the `deckSet` initialization into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new array for each element of the ArrayList, or else every element in the ArrayList is pointing to the same array. So for each of the 4 draws, it will turn 1 number in { 1, 1, 1, 1 } into 0, and on the 5th draw, a stack overflow occurs as there is no more 1s in the shared array.

You can fix the code by moving the new array declaration inside the loop, so a new array is created to be added to the list:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
            Integer[] deckSet = {1, 1, 1, 1}; // Moved inside
            deck.add(deckSet);
        }
```

<s>Doesn't seem like you initialized all the Integers in the arrays in deck to be 1, so the conditional in the if statement is always false.</s>

Consider doing

```
        if(deckSet[shape] == 0){ // Zero for unpicked card
            deckSet[shape] = 1; // One for picked card
            deck.set(num, deckSet);
            card[0] = num;
            card[1] = shape;
            return card;
        }
```

Comment: this is just a portion of my whole code. In the full code i did initialize all the value as 1 for unpicked and 0 for picked cards.
`for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){deck.add(deckSet);}` I did do the loop here to assign the value